# How to evaluate an expression before printing it?

Tags: packages

**Start of Edit**

In response to the comments I have added the following `mwe`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Let's see if this prints: \pgfmathparse{sin(60)}.
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the output is just: "Let's see if this prints: ." 
**End of Edit**

I wanted to populate a table with entries calculated on the basis of constants depending on experiment parameters (like room temperature, pressure and humidity). Instead of hand-calculating the entries each time I make the table, I wanted to code the LaTeX table in the form of expressions that can be evaluated. This way, just by changing the experiment parameters, I can populate the new tables.

Somewhat similar questions have been asked before, e.g. [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521490/variable-evaluation-in-latex), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016725/latex-immediate-evaluation), and [example 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74400/how-to-evaluate-tikz-expression-before-printing-as-text). `Sage`, `calc` and `fp` are some of the solutions that have been suggested.

Submission to journals forms a very important factor in my consideration. Many journals these days accept the `TeX` files and I am reluctant to make submissions that involve heavy packages. `Sage` in spite of being able to evaluate expression the way I intend them to be, is ruled out for the same reason. I found `calc` too cumbersome. Somehow I am not able to find the documentation for `fp`.

All recommendations are welcome. If the `TikZ` package can be somehow employed, that would be perfect. I use it in almost all of my manuscripts.

Comment: The one I would recommend is to use `\pgfmathparse`/`\pgfmathsetmacro`.  If you put together a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70860/can-latex-perform-calculation-like-excel-formula-table/70865#70865

Comment: I am reluctant to make submissions that involve heavy packages.... If the TikZ package can be somehow employed, that would be perfect.  They seem to be somewhat in contradiction, Tikz is a good package but it is massively heavyweight and probably more code than all the other packages that you mention combined. I wonder what _are_ your criterion for acceptable packages in solutions?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry for my ignorance. My criterion for now is that packages which do not depend on other software are alright. Therefore `SageTex` is rejected because it requires the user to install `Sage`.

Comment: I don't know the difference between the two: `parse` and `result`.

Comment: OK that makes sense:-)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel How to use `\pgfmathresult`? I tried the line
`Let's see if this prints: \pgfmathresult{sin(60)}.` which resulted in the 'undefined control sequence' error.

Comment: @ShashankSawant _(Re-Comment:)_ `\pgfmathparse{<arg>}` only parses the argument. `\pgfmathresult` gives back the result. (PGF manual says to `\pgfmathparse`: “This macro parses `<arg>` and returns the result without units in the macro `\pgfmathresult`.” | MWE: `Let's see if this prints: \pgfmathparse{sin(60)}\pgfmathresult.`

Comment: @PeterGrill I fully understood your comment just now. I post MWEs whenever I can. This time I just did not know where to start. Just learnt how to set the value of a variable. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/define-a-variable-in-tikz (bobobobo's answer).

Comment: `fp` documentation: ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fp/README

Comment: @ManuelKuehner A pre-mirror link to the `fp` manual is [CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fp/README) or [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fp/README). @ShashankSawant If you don't use TikZ, `\usepackage{pgf}` suffices. PGF also has a FPU library, which is described in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (ch. 36 “Floating Point Unit Library”) as well.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Ok - thanks. How do I generate per-mirror links?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just forgot to return the result of `\pgfmathparse` by calling **`\pgfmathresult`**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Let's see if this prints: \pgfmathparse{sin(60)}\pgfmathresult.
\end{document}
```

In the [`pgfmanual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) you find more information in section **93.1 Parsing Expressions** (as of pgfmanual version 3.1.1; 2019-03-03).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I guess most of you are computer science/engg guys. I have no clue as to what parsing is. I do understand the basics of programming. But in the basics it is simple. Say in python (for that matter any language) you define a variable `a=2` and if you wish to see it in the control you say `print(a)`. What is parsing in this context?

Comment: Hello. I am not a geek either. I would say that the author of `pgf` just designed it that way: `\pgfmathparse` reads the expression and evaluates (calculates) it. The result is now known to `pgf`. If you want to use the result in the document then the commands `\pgfmathresult` is used to get the last calculated value.

Comment: @ShashankSawant In the context of your Python example, parsing is the Python interpreter reading the text of your code to figure out that it consists of an assignment operation of a variable to a value. This is before *executing* your code or actually running the assignment. I'm not sure if PGF uses the term exactly the same, but it's a similar idea.